# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 243

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npm-install, npm-start

Working on my first react-native project. "npm install" seems to work fine but when I try "npm start" I am greeted with this error message.

```
    This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]? y
Installing the package 'expo-cli'...
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cameronedwards/.npm/_logs/2020-02-03T21_11_28_565Z-debug.log
Installing Expo CLI failed. You can install it manually with:
  npm install --global expo-cli
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 243
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 243
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cameronedwards/.npm/_logs/2020-02-03T21_11_28_613Z-debug.log
```

This is my first time on stack overflow so apologies if format/wording is strange.

Comment: What does your `package.json` file look like?

Comment: this is probably way too much but here's abt 1/10th of the file

Comment: Edit your original post and paste it there

Comment: Also - the official docs should explain how to fix your issue - https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally